# Set 1 field for all records to a given value using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let say I have a table call MyTable, with a bit field call Del_flg, and I want to set Del_flg for all records in MyTable to true. In SQL Server, that could easily be done using the following query:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET [Del_flg] = 1
```

How can I archive the same result using Entity Framework?

Comment: Do you want LINQ query to update the table records?

Comment: you can used foreach loop in EF.

Comment: db.MyTable.ForEach(x => x.Del_flg = 1) like this you can try..you want to all data set Del_flg = 1 using EF?

Comment: @coderwill I've tried your solution but I think it should read db.MyTable.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Del_flg = 1). Also, doesn't that command pull all records into memory before executing the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx) method of the `DbContext.Database`

```
_myDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET [Del_flg] = 1");
```

If you need to do this only once (because your data model has changed), you should consider using an [EF migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) to set this value.

```
public partial class SetDeletedFlagTrue : DbMigration {
    public override void Up() {
        const string update = "UPDATE MyTable SET [Del_flg] = 1";
        Sql(update);
    }

    public override void Down() { /* ... */}
}
```

Comment: Nice! I've tried ExecuteSqlCommand method and it is just as fast as running the query on my server.

Comment: Yes, using ExecuteSqlCommand  bypasses most of EF and goes directly to the server. The drawback is that your query is a string, so it will not be refactored automatically if you rename a property of your data model.